# Long inverse trignometry

Tags: trigonometry

If we are given the following equation: 
$$y =\arctan \frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}+\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
Then we have to prove $x^2 = \sin2y$

I tried by multiplying the eqiuation by 2 on both side  then tried to convert arctan into arcsin.

But it becoes too long to solve

Is there any short method.

Comment: Hint: rationalize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this easily using repetitive [componendo and dividendo](https://brilliant.org/wiki/componendo-and-dividendo/). $$\tan y=\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}+\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$ $$\Rightarrow \frac{1+\tan y}{1-\tan y} =\sqrt{\frac{1+x^2}{1-x^2}}$$ $$\Rightarrow \frac{1+x^2}{1-x^2} = (\frac{1+\tan y}{1-\tan y})^2 $$ $$\Rightarrow x^2 = \frac{(1+\tan y)^2-(1-\tan y)^2}{(1+\tan y)^2+(1-\tan y)^2} = \frac{2\tan y}{1+\tan^{2} y} = \sin 2y$$ Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\tan y=\dfrac{\sqrt{1+x^2}-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}+\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

Use  [Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution)

Comment: Using that it will be too long

Comment: @user123733, Please find my other answer

Answer (score 1):

As $0\le x^2\le$ let $x^2=\cos2u,$  WLOG $0\le2u\le\dfrac\pi2$

$$\tan y=\dfrac{\sqrt{1+x^2}-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}+\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\dfrac{\cos u-\sin u}{\cos u+\sin u}=\tan\left(\dfrac\pi4-u\right)$$

$y=m\pi+\dfrac\pi4-u$ where $m$ is any integer

$\implies2u=2m\pi+\dfrac\pi2-2y\implies x^2=\cos2u=\cdots=\sin2y$

Answer (score -1):

You may use componendo and divedendo.
Thoughts:-

if $a/b=c/d$ then ($a+b)/(a-b)=(c+d)/(c-d)$ and vice-verca.

so $\frac{\tan y + 1}{\tan y - 1}= - \left(\frac{1+x^2}{1-x^2}\right)^{1/2}$

square both sides and then apply componendo & dividendo again to get the desired result.

Comment: Kindly use Mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference