# Problem with my solution of a question of inverse Trigonometric Functions

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

I need to find the value of $tan^{-1}\left[\frac{\sqrt{1\space+\space x^2}\space+\space\sqrt{1\space-\space x^2}}{\sqrt{1\space+\space x^2}\space-\space\sqrt{1\space-\space x^2}}\right]$, where $|x| \space \lt \frac 12$.

I had tried it and reached the following solution:-

$ Since \space x^2 \in [0, \frac 14), sin^{-1}x^2 can\space be \space defined. $

Let $sin^{-1}x^2\space=\space\theta\implies x^2 = sin\theta$

Replacing $x^2$ with $sin\theta,$ the expression becomes:-

$$tan^{-1}\left[\frac{\sqrt{1\space+\space sin\theta} \space+\space\sqrt{1\space-\space sin\theta}}{\sqrt{1\space+\space sin\theta} \space-\space \sqrt{1\space-\space sin\theta}}\right]$$

Using the formulas:-

$i)\space|\space2sin\frac \theta2\space| = |\space\sqrt{1\space+\space sin\theta} \space+\space\sqrt{1\space-\space sin\theta}\space| $

$ii)\space|\space2cos\frac \theta2\space| = |\space\sqrt{1\space+\space sin\theta} \space-\space\sqrt{1\space-\space sin\theta}\space| $

The expression therefore simplifies to

$$tan^{-1}[tan\frac \theta2]$$.

Since $\frac \theta2 \in [0, \frac{sin^{-1}\frac14}{2})$, therefore expression becomes

$\frac\theta2 = \frac {sin^{-1}x^2}2 = \frac π4 - \frac 12 cos^{-1}x^2$.

However, the answer is $\frac π4 + \frac 12 cos^{-1}x^2$.

I don't know where I am wrong. Please help.

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2066906/42969, or this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2644104/42969.

Comment: I believe there is something wrong with $i)$, $ii)$ formulae. Check $\theta=0$.

Comment: @Ivan Kaznacheyeu, Thank you so much. I got it. I tried to prove it and then found the formula is not true for every θ. It was a mistake of mine. Thank you.